# Distribute the amount value into multiple field base on date start and date end

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'd like to seek help with my access database. i would like to distribute value (format on currency) into multiple field base on date start and date end.

for example on:

```
 if field Spend Amount value is - $10,000 
 if field start date is - Jan-2018
 if Field end date is - April-2018
```

then the Jan field will be $2,500

```
 and Feb field should be $2,500
 Mar field also $2,500
 april field also $2,500
```

basically the amount should be equally divided base on start month and end month category

appreciate your help please

Answer (score 0):

The expression to put in your update can look something like this:

```
 Amount/(DateDiff("m",StartDate,EndDate)+1)
```

This will divide 10.000 with 4. The 4 comes from the DateDiff that counts the number of months between the start and end (which results in 3) plus one. Make sure to test edge cases like Nov 30 to Dec 1, leap years and other problematic combinations.

Edit, clarification - this is not VBA. Put it in an update statement

Comment: Hi Sam, it work thanks.. it gives the total cost value per month base on date range. but how can I distribute the monthly value amount with the correct field on another table.

to give more clarity. I have another table where field name Jan-2019 | Feb-2019 | Mar-2019 | April-2019 | May-2019 | AND SO ON TILL 2022 for example.

now how can I automatically input the monthly value in the correct month field?

thanks for your help